# Differene between Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio and normal eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss-developer-studio

What is the differene between Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio and normal eclipse IDE

Comment: Developer Studio is fine if you are targeting JBoss EAP. It is configured to be closely integrated with EAP, and should work very well with the version of JBoss AS that was used for EAP. However, if you want to use the latest features and releases, then stick with Eclipse + JBoss Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia [JBoss Developer Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBoss_Developer_Studio) says:

> JBoss Developer Studio (JBDS) is a development environment created
>   and currently developed by JBoss (a division of Red Hat) and Exadel.
>
> It integrates and certifies both tooling and runtime components by
>   combining Eclipse, Eclipse Tooling, and the JBoss Enterprise
>   Application Platform.

See the article for further details.